# How can I use regex to extract the part of a string that is enclosed between CDATA?

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract a string enclosed in CDATA tag using php?
For instance I have

```
$str = "<![CDATA[this is my text]]>";
```

Using regex how can I extract the string "this is my text"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex: `/<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>/`:

```
$str = "<![CDATA[this is my text]]>";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // this is my text
```

The regex looks for `<![CDATA[` followed by any characters until the first `]]>` is encountered.

Comment: why not use regular `(.*?)` in the middle part?

Comment: @zerkms Yeah just realized that haha. I've been doing a lot of regex in an engine without greey vs. non-greedy quantifiers lately lol

Answer (score 2):

if your string always starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>` you can use substr()

```
$str = "<![CDATA[this is my text]]>";
$output = substr($str,9,strlen($str)-12);
echo $output;
```